# how to call funtion on preg match php code

Tags: php, preg-match

i have code..

```
<?php
function word() 
{
     $arr = array("/c/","/b/","/c/");
     echo $arr[array_rand($arr)];
}
$text = "a";
if(preg_match("$word()", $text)) {
     $result = "found";
}else{
     $result = "not found";
}
echo $result;
?>
```

how to call function `word();` into `preg_match`.
I want to randomly search the words in `preg_match`.
I tried but it didn't work.
how to fix this code.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? `$text` doesn't seem to be related to `$arr`. `$word()` also would try to call a function with the name by the value of `$word`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your function `word()` return the random string instead of echoing it you can use it as any value by calling the function.

```php
function word() {
    $arr = array("/c/","/b/","/c/");
    return $arr[array_rand($arr)];
}

if( preg_match(word(), $text) ) {
    $result = "found";
}
else {
    $result = "not found";
}

echo $result;
```

If it makes it more clear, this is the same as storing the result from the function in a variable and use that.

These are all the same:

```php
// Writing the pattern in place.
preg_match("/a/", $text);

// Storing it in a variable before use.
$to_match = "/a/";
preg_match($to_match, $text);

// Storing it in a variable where the value is returned from a function.
$to_match = word();
preg_match($to_match, $text);

// Using a function directly in the call to `preg_match`.
preg_match(word(), $text);
```

Comment: Admittedly I'm tired, but couldn't tell what they were trying to do until I saw your answer.